# Replace a special part of a JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object called `users` like this:

```
[{"givenName":"helen","sn":"brown","phone":"44512","details":"512"},{{"givenName":"John","sn":"Doe","phone":"44600","details":"512"}]
```

I apply `json.stringify` method to convert this JavaScript object to a JSON string. Then, I use `replace` to replace `512` value with `active`. Here is my code to implement this:

```
var jsonUsers = JSON.stringify(users).replace(/512/g, 'active');
```

The problem is that when I use this code, it replaces all `512` with `active` (for example in my example, it changes`details` values and also it changes the `phone` value of the first person with something like `44active`), but I want to apply this replacement only on the values of the `details` key, not on whole of the string (for example I don't want to check and replace the value of the `phone`). How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just modify the object *before* running it through `JSON.stringify()` so you can adequately target each object's `details` key properly...?

Comment: Why are you using JSON.stringify(). You can directly change, using array loop (map)

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to replace parts of a JSON. Fix it while it's an object instead.

```js
const arr = [{"givenName":"helen","sn":"brown","phone":"44512","details":"512"},{"givenName":"John","sn":"Doe","phone":"44600","details":"512"}];

for (const item of arr) {
  if (item.details === '512') {
    item.details = 'active';
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: It didn't work for me and when I `console.log(item.details)` inside the loop, the value is undefined.

Comment: Press "Run code snippet" to see it working. If your input array of objects is as you say, then iterating over the array and reassigning the `item.details` will do what you want. If your input array of objects actually isn't as stated in the question, please edit the question to clarify what you actually have.

Answer (score 0):

```
const users = [{"givenName":"helen","sn":"brown","phone":"44512","details":"512"},{"givenName":"John","sn":"Doe","phone":"44600","details":"512"}]
```

Now use array.map()

```
const newArray = users.map(e => {
    return {...e, details: e.details==512 ? "active" : e.details};
});
```

Comment: It didn't work for me and when I `console.log(e.details)`, the value is undefined.

Comment: See here, it works https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3y3n6xxfa

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to replace the text from details property then no need to convert the whole object into a string. You can simply iterate over the array using `Array.map()` method and then replace the `details` property value based on the `regex`.

Try this **:**

```js
const jsonObj = [{
  "givenName": "helen",
  "sn": "brown",
  "phone": "44512",
  "details": "512"
}, {
  "givenName": "John",
  "sn": "Doe",
  "phone": "44600",
  "details": "512"
}];

const res = jsonObj.map(obj => {
    obj.details = obj.details.replace(/512/g, 'active');
  return obj;
});

console.log(res);
```